# matching list structure other than map() in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to write a recursive function that will perform some action on every object within the list and then output a new list that matches the structure of the processed list exactly. I had some help from users here, but in my example i tried strings which happen to be iterable and work well with map(). However when I am applying it to other data types like int that are not iterable, i get an error:

```
def process_list(_list):
new_list = []
for x in _list:
    if is_list(x):
        new_list.append(process_list(x))
    else:
        new_list.append(map(lambda y: y + 1, x))
return new_list

def is_list(l):
return type(l) == types.ListType

_list = [[0,1,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,2]],[0,1,2]]
```

i am using Integers as an example here because they are not iterable and i am expecting that map() will fail on a list of integers. Imagine any other data type that is not iterable. Is there another way to define this that will let me perform some function(s) on objects within the list and then create an output list that matches the input list?

thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to iterate (by using the `map()` function) over `x`, which is not iterable in most cases. The reason you can do it for strings is because they are iterable objects in themselves, which is why you didn't run into this right away. You really don't need to use `map()` at all in your for loop... you could just do

```
for x in _list:
    if is_list(x):
        new_list.append(process_list(x))
    else:
        new_list.append(x+1)
```

Really the best thing you could do is use map directly:

```
def process_list(_list):
    return map( lambda x: process_list(x) if type(x)==list else x+1, _list )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the `else` clause so it performs simple addition on the item. No `map` or `lambda` required.

```
import types

def process_list(_list):
    new_list = []
    for x in _list:
        if is_list(x):
            new_list.append(process_list(x))
        else:
            new_list.append(x+1)
    return new_list

def is_list(l):
    return type(l) == types.ListType

_list = [[[0,1,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,2]],[0,1,2]]

print process_list(_list)
```

Result:

```
[[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], [1, 2, 3]]
```

---

If you want calls to `process_list` to look more like `map`, you can require an additional parameter, which indicates what kind of processing should be done.

```
import types

def process_list(func, _list):
    new_list = []
    for x in _list:
        if is_list(x):
            new_list.append(process_list(func, x))
        else:
            new_list.append(func(x))
    return new_list

def is_list(l):
    return type(l) == types.ListType

_list = [[[0,1,2],[0,1,2],[0,1,2]],[0,1,2]]

print process_list(lambda x: x+1, _list)
```

Answer (score 0):

check with `isinstance` to see what the type is and base your logic on that:

```
def process_list(_list):
    new_list = []
    for x in _list:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            new_list.append(process_list(x))
        elif isinstance(x, (int, float)):
           new_list.append(x+1)                
        else:
            new_list.append(map(lambda y: y + 1, x))
    return new_list
```

You can also use collections.Iterable to find iterable elements after you have checked for a list, if you wanted to only call map on strings you would use `isinstance(x, basestring)` what you check for all depends on what you are trying to achieve:

```
from collections import Iterable
def process_list(_list):
    new_list = []
    for x in _list:
        if isinstance(x, list):
            new_list.append(process_list(x))
        elif isinstance(x, Iterable):
            new_list.append(map(lambda y: y + 1, x))
        else:
            new_list.append(x+1)
    return new_list
```